# Height of fitted distribution much higher than real data

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit

For what reason can the height of a fitted distribution be much has higher than the real data it was fitted on? Does it just mean that the distribution does not fit the data or that I have too few data? I have attached a photo[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not plotting the histogram of the data in the probability scale. Compare for instance:

```
hist(rnorm(1000))
```

against

```
hist(rnorm(1000), probability =T)
```